# What does IBO on a bow mean and how is it calculated?

Tags: bow-hunting

When I look at bow manufacturers' websites, I see bows are rated with an IBO for their arrows speed.  I was wondering what IBO stands for and how it is calculated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A.M.O.(Archery Manufacturing Organization) and I.B.O. (International Bowhunters Association) both have a method for testing arrow speed from bows and although they are different both can be used to compare equipment for relative speed.

Both of the speed testing standards use a constant drawlength, arrow weight and bow weight to test bowspeed. These are the way the two differ.

A.M.O.

Under this standard the bow being tested will have a maximum pull weight of 60lbs. The arrow will have a grain weight of 540(9 grains of arrow weight per pound of bow weight). The draw length will be set at 30 inches. The chronograph used for measuring the speed will be placed at point blank range for testing.

I.B.O.

Under this standard the bow being tested will have a maximum pull weight of 70lbs. The arrow will have a grain weight of 350(5 grains of arrow weight per pound of bow weight). The draw length will be set at 30 inches. The chronograph used for measuring the speed will be placed at point blank range for testing.

The article continues here:
http://www.archeryexchange.com/shopcontent.asp?type=amoibo